# i want to open a file in the root directory in my c++ application in write mode.

Tags: permissions, files, qt, c++

I have a file in the root directory which I want to open for editing in my QT application.  Generally we use "sudo (editor) filepath" to open the file with roots permissions. But i want to achieve this in my c++ QT application. Any kind of help is appreciable. Thank you.

Comment: `sudo (editor) filepath` runs _(editor)_ with Administrator privileges passing _filepath_ to it as a parameter.  So `sudo my-c-application` would run _my-c-application_ as with the required privileges.  Or if your application has a GUI `gksudo my-c-application`.  Replace _my-c-application_ with the name of your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I know you can do it in two ways.

1. Remove or disable the root prompt when ever we are trying to access the root mounted dir. But the pros & cons are mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Remove_Password_Prompt_For_sudo) very clearly.
2. Everytime if you will access the same directory/file then you can change file permission to that directory as everyone access& modify it. for that consideration [read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) page.

so choose what best suits you.

hope that helps a bit.

Comment: The second option looks interesting. But is it possible to give permission to a file such that only my application can access it when the application is ran by any user. but those any user can't modify the file unless they are using the application.

Comment: No you can't make it for application but you can make it for current login user  . Look at the link I gave you.